# Strip html to remove all js/css/html tags to give actual text(displayed on browser) to use it for indexing and search

Tags: php, indexing, full-text-search, search-engine

I have tried strip_tag but it still leaves inline js : (function(){..}) and also inline css #button{}

I need to extract pure text from html without any JS function or styling or tags so that I can index it and use for for my search functionality.

html2text also doesnt seem to solve the problem!

**EDIT**

PHP Code:

```
$url = "http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2011/11/development-setup-for-neo4j-and-php_05.html";

$fileHeaders = @get_headers($url);
if( $fileHeaders[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" || $fileHeaders[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
        {
            $content = strip_tags(file_get_contents($url));
        }
```

OUTPUT :

$content =

```
(function() { var a=window,c="jstiming",d="tick";var e=function(b){this.t={};this.tick=function(b,o,f){f=void 0!=f?f:(new Date).getTime();this.t[b]=[f,o]};this[d]("start",null,b)},h=new e;a.jstiming={Timer:e,load:h};if(a.performance&&a.performance.timing){var i=a.performance.timing,j=a[c].load,k=i.navigationStart,l=i.responseStart;0=k&&(j[d]("_wtsrt",void 0,k),j[d]("wtsrt_","_wtsrt",l))}
try{var m=null;a.chrome&&a.chrome.csi&&(m=Math.floor(a.chrome.csi().pageT));null==m&&a.gtbExternal&&(m=a.gtbExternal.pageT());null==m&&a.external&&(m=a.external.pageT);m&&(a[c].pt=m)}catch(n){};a.tickAboveFold=function(b){var g=0;if(b.offsetParent){do g+=b.offsetTop;while(b=b.offsetParent)}b=g;750>=b&&a[c].load[d]("aft")};var p=!1;function q(){p||(p=!0,a[c].load[d]("firstScrollTime"))}a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener("scroll",q,!1):a.attachEvent("onscroll",q);
 })();











Everyman Software: Development Setup for Neo4j and PHP: Part 2



#navbar-iframe { display:block }






if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', prettyPrint);
  }
var a=navigator,b="userAgent",c="indexOf",f="&m=1",g="(^|&)m=",h="?",i="?m=1";function j(){var d=window.location.href,e=d.split(h);switch(e.length){case 1:return d+i;case 2:return 0



2011-11-05







Development Setup for Neo4j and PHP: Part 2





This is Part 2 of a series on setting up a development environment for building projects using the graph database Neo4j and PHP. In Part 1 of this series, we set up unit test and development databases.  In this part, we'll build a skeleton project that includes unit tests, and a minimalistic user interface.

All the files will live under a directory on our web server. In a real project, you'll probably want only the user interface files under the web server directory and your testing and library files somewhere more protected.

Also, I won't be using any specific PHP framework.  The principles in t
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code with in-line JS and CSS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a small snippet I always use to remove all the hidden text from a webpage, including everything inbetween `<script>, <style>, <head>` etc tags. Also it will replace all the multiple occurrences of any kind of whitespace with a single space.

```
<?php
$url = "http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2011/11/development-setup-for-neo4j-and-php_05.html";
    $fileHeaders = @get_headers($url);
    if( $fileHeaders[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" || $fileHeaders[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
    {
            $content = strip_html_tags(file_url_contents($url));
    }

############################################
//To fetch the $url by using cURL
function file_url_contents($url){
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
} //file_url_contents ENDS

//To remove all the hidden text not displayed on a webpage
function strip_html_tags($str){
    $str = preg_replace('/(<|>)\1{2}/is', '', $str);
    $str = preg_replace(
        array(// Remove invisible content
            '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            ),
        "", //replace above with nothing
        $str );
    $str = replaceWhitespace($str);
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    return $str;
} //function strip_html_tags ENDS

//To replace all types of whitespace with a single space
function replaceWhitespace($str) {
    $result = $str;
    foreach (array(
    "  ", " \t",  " \r",  " \n",
    "\t\t", "\t ", "\t\r", "\t\n",
    "\r\r", "\r ", "\r\t", "\r\n",
    "\n\n", "\n ", "\n\t", "\n\r",
    ) as $replacement) {
    $result = str_replace($replacement, $replacement[0], $result);
    }
    return $str !== $result ? replaceWhitespace($result) : $result;
}
############################
?>
```

See it in action here http://codepad.viper-7.com/txIxfE
  And output: http://pastebin.com/a86jd17s

Comment: still doesnt take care of inline/embedded javascripts/css : (function() { var a=window,c="jstiming",d="tick";var e=function(b){this.t={};this.tick=function(b,o,f){f=void 0!=f?f:(new Date).getTime();this.t[b]=[f,o]};thisd},h=new e;a.jstiming={Timer:e,load:h};if(a.performance&&a.performance.timing){var i=a.performance.timing,j=a[c].load,k=i.navigationStart,l=i.responseStart;0=k&&(jd};var p=!1;function q(){p||(p=!0,a[c].loadd)}a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener("scroll",q,!1):a.attachEvent("onscroll",q); })();

Comment: Here is this code in action by using your given url: [http://codepad.viper-7.com/txIxfE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/txIxfE)  And here is the output text:[http://pastebin.com/a86jd17s](http://pastebin.com/a86jd17s)  Take a look on this out-put text and let me know which lines/section is unwanted. Refer by line-number.

Comment: Please note that you need to pass your original string with all the HTML intact through this function, not the one which you get after using strip_html(). Because in the case of latter, `<head>, </head>, <style>, <script>` etc identifier tags are already stripped and thus my function cannot distinguish between hidden & displayed text.

Comment: In reply to your first comment, on probing I found that the fragmment you are reffering `function() { var a=window,c="jsti.....` is on the 7th line on the source page and **is enclosed** within `<script>` & `</script>` tags. Do not pass your whole string to my function `after` doing `strip_tags`. Give the string as it is intact with all `head, style, script tags` present.

Comment: `I need to write a generic function that can take any url and remove all non textual data(html tags/js/css) so that this could be given to an indexing search engine` This is what this function do.. Give it a `URL`, not a `strip_tags($url)`.

Comment: Codepad link is working here. But you can do without the link. Just use it as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nice code, it helped me to remove js and css from strings.

Answer (score 0):

[strip_tags()](http://us.php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php) will remove everything that is inside < and >. So, e.g., if you have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello world');</script>
```

It will be reduced to

```
alert('hello world');
```

This will not be executed but just displayed on your site.

Alternatively, try [htmlentities()](http://us.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php) to convert "<" to "&lt" and > to "&gt" so it can be displayed safely without executing anything.

If, instead, your question is about extracting data from tags, better use regular expressions. E.g., if you have something like

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

you can simply use [preg_match()](http://us.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) to get the word "Google" from the whole link:

```
$content='<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
$regex="#<a href=".*?">(.+?)</a>#";
preg_match($regex,$content,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

By the way - $match[1] will have the match cleared from any tags anyways, while $match[0] won't. To get more than one match, use [preg_match_all()](http://us.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: I need to write a generic function that can take any url and remove all non textual data(html tags/js/css) so that this could be given to an indexing search engine. Preg_match is not a solution because of the number of possibilities tht I might need to filter. I dont want to end up writing another library which in itself is a whole project!